# Django Socail-Auth and My Auth

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth, socialauth

i tried to install django social auth,
which is located on 
https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth
how can i associate a regular registration and social auth
for example a user doesn't have any account in twitter or facebook etc ..
how can i associate django.contrib.auth with social auth

by giving him the choice of choosing either to register normal registration or using his account in twitter or facebook

Answer (score 0):

`django-social-auth` provides views for authenticated with a particular backend (such as Google, Facebook, or Twitter).  Take a look at the code defined in `social_auth`'s URLconf: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/urls.py

Once you've got `social_auth` installed, if you want to log in with Twitter, you'd visit the `begin` url specifying the appropriate backend (e.g. /login/twitter/).  The `social_auth` app would then redirect your user to Twitter, at which point they'd authorize your app, then you'd get redirected back the `complete` url (e.g. /complete/twitter).

If you wanted to associate a Twitter account with an existing user (that is, a User created via the `admin` app, or something like `django-registration`), you'd visit the `associate_begin` url (e.g. "/associate/twitter/").

This all assumes that your root URLconf contains an entry like:

```
url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
```